# OpenGL - Alternate between drawing with or without texture

Tags: opengl, textures, shader

In my game engine, I often change between drawing textured and non-textured shapes. I'm wondering, what is the most efficient way to make this distinction? For example, suppose we have two methods, `DrawRectangle(Color color)` and `DrawRectangleTextured(int textureId)` and we have no control of the order in which they are called.

I have thought of three possible ways of dealing with this:

1) Have two different shader programs, one that takes a texture and one that doesn't. Then select the appropriate shader before drawing. This seems like a good solution in terms of efficiency, but I'm not sure about the overhead of swapping programs all the time. Furthermore, it's troublesome to have to always keep track of two programs, making it difficult to maintain and extend.

2) Make a completely white texture and treat non-textured drawing as textured drawing with that white texture. This means whenever we draw with color, we have to upload redundant texture coordinates and the fragment shader has to do a little bit of extra work.

3) Use a uniform value specifying whether to draw with a texture or not. Not sure if this has any advantages over option 2).

Is there a common and efficient way to deal with this problem?

Comment: State sorting is key in such scenarios. You sort according to shader first. That means you'll never interleave textured and un-textured primitives. Next, you identify how many textured object share the same texture and sort according to that. This way you only bind one texture one time. That's basically it. But beware - if the overhead of sorting your shaders and objects is higher than the brute force approach it doesn't make much sense to do it.

Comment: Thanks for that answer :) As mentioned, I'm building a game engine, and I would like to allow users to create custom shaders. I'm not sure how those shaders would work, but it's reasonable to believe sorting would be difficult. Do you think having a white texture and just use one textured shader would make sense? Basically, is there a lot of overhead in uploading those texture coordinates?

Comment: It doesn't matter whether shaders are provided by you or the user. You can still identify which objects are to be rendered with which shaders - thus you can always sort by shader in some way. If you don't have any other logic in the shader except for "take a sample at this UV coordinate from sampler2D xy and assign the value as the fragment color" then yes, you can texture any object providing UV coordinates with that single shader and varying 2D textures bound to the sampler. As soon as you need more complex logic, you need more shaders.